# Rails validate error messages remove keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently writing a little framework within my rails app to map error messages to form fields. I have added this simple validation to my `lunch_choice` model.

```
def check_dupe
  user = User.find(user_id)
  return unless user

  if user.lunch_choices.map{|lc| lc.name}.any?{|n| n == name }
    errors.add(:lunch_choice, "with that name already exists")
  end
end
```

That validation produces the following error messages.

```
{ lunch_choice: "Lunch choice with that name already exists" }
```

This is great and all, but I'd like it to read something like this.

```
{ name: "Lunch choice with that name already exists" }
```

The purpose of this is so I can take the key of the hash and map that key to the form field and display the error underneath.

I tried adding the validation error like this

```
errors.add(:name, "Lunch choice with that name already exists")
```

But that produces

```
{ name: "Name Lunch choice with that name already exists" }
```

I can't find any documentation stating where I can remove the key name from the actually message generated by Rails. I'd rather not go about monkey patching this. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Rails guide has the topics covered. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: I would write a [Custom Validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) that would just work like all other Rails vadlidations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really just duplicating the functionality of the existing [`validates_uniqueness_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) validation (while introducing several bugs / problems) and making busywork for yourself.

```
class LunchChoice < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, 
     message: '^Lunch choice with that name already exists'
end
```

When an validation message begins with `^` Rails does not prefix it with the name of the column.

If you want to scope this per user you would use the `scope` option:

```
class LunchChoice < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, 
     message: '^Lunch choice with that name already exists',
     scope: :user_id
end
```

And in any form builder you can simply get the wrapped object and from there its errors object:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:meal_choices) |mcf| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= mcf.label :name %>
      <%= mcf.text_input :name %>
      <% mcf.object.full_messages_for(:name).each do |m| %>
        <p><%= m %></p> 
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Suggested reading:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

`errors.add(:name, "Lunch choice with that name already exists")`

here you use the symbol `:name`. what you want is the content of the variable `name`, so do

`errors.add(name.to_sym, "Lunch choice with that name already exists")`